# MVC две модели одно представление

Tags: laravel

На базе фреймворка laravel решил написать блог.
Столкнулся с проблемой: я не знаю, как вывести комментарии.

В `BlogController` для вывода поста использую следующую функцию:

```
 public function showPost($slug, Request $request)
    {
        $post = Post::with('tags')->whereSlug($slug)->firstOrFail();
        $tag = $request->get('tag');
        if ($tag) {
            $tag = Tag::whereTag($tag)->firstOrFail();
        }
        $comment = Comments::find($slug);
        var_dump($post->layout);
        return view($post->layout, compact('post', 'tag', 'comment'));
    }
```

на выводе

```
<div class="comments">
    <ul>
        @foreach($comment as $comment)
            <li>Автор: {{$comment->author}}<br>{{$comment->content}}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
```

на что получаю ошибку :

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
>   (View: /home/www/blog/laravel/resources/views/blog/comment/comment.blade.php)

Comment: $comment as $comment выглядит довольно странно, сделайте уж список с именем $comments

Comment: ну эт конечно.. не обратил внимания при копипасте.
Undefined variable: comments

Comment: Укажите, есть ли у вас связь между моделями `Comments` и `Post`. Какого типа первичный ключ в `Comments`? Точно текстовый? Кроме того, метод `find` вернет только одну запись. Вам же нужна коллекция. Следовательно, делайте поиск по условию через `where()` и `get()`

Comment: $table->string('slug')->unique();

Comment: `return view($post->layout, compact('post', 'tag', 'comment'));` - здесь у вас comment или comments

Comment: $comment = Comments::where('article_id', '=', $slug)->get();

Comment: изменил запрос на  $comment = Comments::where('article_id', '=', $slug)->get(); получил комментарий . Спасибо - не знал что find получает одну строку.
apelsinka223  да .. а вот тут и ошибка .. спасибо разобрался